# Is it possible to schedule a page edit to go live on a certain date?

Tags: scheduled-posts

On one of our websites, we have a page with a text block (Visual Composer) about a special offer which is available until the 1st of July. I, of course, would like that to disappear as soon as the 1st of July comes around... But here in the UK, that's a Saturday, so nobody will be around to make that amendment. So, would it be possible, via a plugin or otherwise, to remove that text block, but then schedule the publication of that amendment to go live on the 1st, similar to how you can schedule the publication of blog posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Show/Hide Content at Set Time plugin to to show the content on scheduled time or date.

```
[time-restrict on="2017/06/26 18:00:00"]your content Will show after 06/26/2017 at 6pm[/time-restrict]
```

more examples according to your need can be seen on plugin page

Comment: Just found this plugin, thank you! I've found that you can wrap a Visual Composer row with a shortcode by finding the [vc-row] and [/vc-row] tags for said row and then placing the shortcode tags around those in the classic editor.

Comment: happy to help you :)